# PhoneGap InAppBrowser: open iOS Safari Browser

Tags: ios, cordova, inappbrowser

In our PhoneGap iOS application, we are using the InAppBrowser plugin to display some content, and we need to open a page in Safari from within the InAppBrowser.

How can we have links from *within* the InAppBrowser open in Safari?

Comment: You are more likely to get an answer if you are more specific. When do you need to open Safari? Is it from a user action, or for some other reason? Please expand your question.

Comment: From InAppBrowser I want to open External link in Safari Browser. I am able to open Safari Browser using following code. But In InAppBrowser same link is also open.                                        function iabLoadStart(event) {
    console.log("iabLoadStart: " + event.type + ' - ' + event.url);
    if (event.url.indexOf("openinSafari") != -1) {
        window.open(event.url, '_system');        
    }
}

Comment: So if you are able to open Safari, what is the problem exactly?

Comment: But Same link is open in both InAppBrowser & Safari Browser. But it should open in Safari Browser not in InAppBrowser.

Comment: Try calling `event.preventDefault()` first thing in the function, before you do any checks or open Safari. That will prevent the default even action from being executed.

Comment: event.preventDefault() is not working in function iabLoadStart(event) { if (event.url.indexOf("openinSafari") != -1) { window.open(event.url, '_system'); } }

Comment: If there's a problem with your code, edit it (your code) into the question, don't post it in comments.

Comment: @AdamTuttle That issue is that the 'event' is a special Cordova event that doesn't support `preventDefault` and is relevant to this question.

Answer (score 6):

From the [phonegap documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#window.open):

> Opens a URL in a new InAppBrowser instance, the current browser instance, or the system browser.
>
> ```
> var ref = window.open(url, target, options);
> ```
>
> - ref: Reference to the InAppBrowser window. (InAppBrowser)
> - url: The URL to load (String). Call encodeURI() on this if the URL contains Unicode characters.
> - target: The target in which to load the URL, an optional parameter that defaults to _self. (String)
>
>   - _self: Opens in the Cordova WebView if the URL is in the white list, otherwise it opens in the InAppBrowser.
>   - _blank: Opens in the InAppBrowser.
>   - _system: Opens in the system's web browser.

So to answer your question, use:

```
window.open(your_url, '_system', opts);
```

Note that the domain will need to be white-listed.

---

### Update 4/25/2014:

I think I kind of misunderstood the question (thanks to commenter @peteorpeter) -- you want to have some way to click a link in the InAppBrowser and have that open in the system browser (e.g. Mobile Safari on iOS). This is possible, but it will require some forethought and cooperation between the app developer and the person responsible for the links on the page.

When you create an IAB instance, you get a reference to it back:

```
var ref = window.open('http://foo.com', '_blank', {...});
```

You can [register a few event listeners](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#addEventListener) on that reference:

```
ref.addEventListener('loadStart', function(event){ ... });
```

This particular event is fired every time the URL of the IAB changes (e.g. a link is clicked, the server returns a 302, etc...), and you can inspect the new URL.

To break out into the system browser, you need some sort of flag defined in the URL. You could do any number of things, but for this example let's assume there's a `systemBrowser` flag in the url:

**.....html?foo=1&systemBrowser=true**

You'll look for that flag in your event handler, and when found, kick out to the system browser:

```
ref.addEventListener('loadStart', function(event){
    if (event.url.indexOf('systemBrowser') > 0){
        window.open(event.url, '_system', null);
    }
});
```

Note that this is *not* the best method for detecting the flag in the url (could lead to false positives, possibly) and I'm pretty sure that PhoneGap whitelist rules will still apply.

Comment: This doesn't work when the link originates _inside_ the InAppBrowser, which I believe is the question posed (at least in Cordova 3.4.1/iOS).  In my testing, links within the IAB always stayed within the IAB regardless of any `target` value.

Comment: Thanks for the prod. I updated my answer to explain how that would work.

Comment: 'loadstart' must be all lowercase, 'loadStart' doesn't work.  Also, this doesn't stop the link from loading in the InAppBrowser, it loads there as well as in Safari.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately `target=_system` does not work from within the InAppBrowser.  (This would work if the link originated in the parent app, though.)

You could add an event listener to the IAB and sniff for a particular url pattern, as you mention in your comments, if that fit your use case.

```
iab.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event) {
   if (event.url.indexOf("openinSafari") != -1) { 
        window.open(event.url, '_system'); 
    } 
}
```

The 'event' here is not a real browser event - it is a construct of the IAB plugin - and doesn't support `event.preventDefault()`, so the IAB will also load the url (in addition to Safari). You might try to handle that event *within the IAB*, with something like:

```
iab.addEventListener('loadstop', function(event) {
   iab.executeScript('functionThatPreventsOpenInSafariLinksFromGoingAnywhere');  
}
```

...which I have not tested.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't even think to read your answer before updating mine. I see we are suggesting basically the same thing. :)

Comment: No worries - better 2 places than none!

Answer (score 2):

This message is for clarification:

If you open an another with window.open by catching a link on loadstart, it will kill yor eventhandlers that assigned to first IAB.

For example,

```
iab = window.open('http://example.com', '_blank', 'location=no,hardwareback=yes,toolbar=no');
iab.addEventListener('loadstop', function(event) {console.log('stop: ' + event.url);});
iab.addEventListener('loaderror', function(event) { console.log('loaderror: ' + event.message); });
iab.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event) {
    if (event.url.indexOf("twitter") != -1){
        var ref2 = window.open(event.url, '_system', null);

    }
});
```

When the second window.open executed, it will kill all the event listeners that you binded before. Also loadstop event will not be fired after that window.open executed.

I'm finding another way to avoid but nothing found yet..

Comment: Very much. Did you find a solution to rebind the events?

Answer (score 0):

`window.open()` doesn't work for me from within an InAppBrowser, whether or not I add a script reference to cordova.js to get support for `window.open(...'_system')`, so I came up with the following solution which tunnels the "external" URL back to the IAB host through the hashtag so it can be opened there.

Inside the InAppBrowser instance (I'm using AngularJS, but you can replace `angular.element` with `jQuery` or `$` if you're using jQuery):

```
angular.element(document).find('a').on('click', function(e) {
    var targetUrl = angular.element(this).attr('href');
    if(targetUrl.indexOf('http') === 0) {
        e.preventDefault();
        window.open('#' + targetUrl);
    }
});
```

Note that that's the native `window.open` above, not cordova.js's `window.open`.  Also, the handler code assumes that all URLs that start with `http` should be externally loaded.  You can change the filter as you like to allow some URLs to be loaded in the IAB and others in Safari.

Then, in the code from the parent that created the InAppBrowser:

```
inAppBrowser.addEventListener('loadstart', function(e) {
    if(e.url.indexOf('#') > 0) {
        var tunneledUrl = e.url.substring(e.url.indexOf('#') + 1);
        window.open(tunneledUrl, '_system', null);
    }
});
```

With this solution the IAB remains on the original page and doesn't trigger a back-navigation arrow to appear, and the `loadstart` handler is able to open the requested URL in Safari.